# PageViewController showing a black screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

In storyboard I have a `UIPageViewController` and this is my code

```
class ReservedTimesViewController: UIPageViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}

extension ReservedTimesViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReservedTimesTableViewController")
        print(controller)
   return controller
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReservedTimesTableViewController")
        print(controller)
        return controller
    }
```

and this is my `ReservedTimesTableViewController` in story board
[image]

but I'm getting a black screen. Why it's not working correct?

Comment: check if you have set delegate and datasource for page controller

Comment: Why are you using `UITableViewController` as `UIPageViewController`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On loading your controller you have to set your initial page by using this code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dataSource = self;
    self.setViewControllers([getViewControllerAtIndex(index: 0)] as [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func getViewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ReservedTimesTableViewController
{
    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    let reservedTimesTableViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReservedTimesTableViewController") as! ReservedTimesTableViewController
    return reservedTimesTableViewController
}
```

After when you try to scroll your page then the datasource methods will do their work.