# UIPageViewController showing black screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

My UIPageViewController appears as a black screen when run.

It's the root view controller set in app delegage:

```
    window = UIWindow()
    let mainPageViewController = MainPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    window?.rootViewController = mainPageViewController
```

This is my code for MainPageViewController:

```
class MainPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource 
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataSource = self

        let profileController = ProfileController()
        let viewControllers = [profileController]
        self.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The profilecontroller which i'm trying to set as the initial page is a normal UIViewController.

I've have tried a lot of stuff, but it always just shows a black screen. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting the backgroundColor to white by doing `view.backgroundColor = .white` in the viewDidLoad() function?

Comment: Yes, and the background color of the viewcontroller it's supposed to display is also white.

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Try the solution in below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/42764778/7956211

Comment: I'm not using storyboards no

Comment: I tried your code, and it works for me.. Try to add `window?.makeKeyAndVisible()` after setting it as the rootViewController... Maybe that will help

Comment: Although that should not cause it.. However, the PageViewController looks fine. Try maybe creating a plain new UIViewController, set its background to white and set it instead of profileController - maybe the problem is there..

Comment: Thanks @MilanNosáľ, that was indeed the problem!

Comment: when you are creating window programatically  you should always set the size of the window to the full bounds of the screen, see developer guideline :-https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH4-SW3

Comment: Thanks for the tip @PushpendraMishra

Comment: welcome! @Elhoej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PageViewController is perfectly fine. Your process of setting the rootViewController however misses following:

```
window = UIWindow()
let mainPageViewController = MainPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
window?.rootViewController = mainPageViewController
// This line will make it visible
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame:  UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let mainPageViewController = MainPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    window?.rootViewController = mainPageViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't sure what your problem is, if your problem is `you don't know why your screen is black?`, I think you should set this in appDelegate:

```
window.backgroundColor = .white
```

and this to your controller:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .white
```

Comment: The UIPageViewController is supposed to display the profilecontroller, which has many subviews etc.